# Show UL of Parent LI on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out the jQuery that I need to write for the following function. When someone clicks onto the span 'expand', I'm hoping that I can show the sub-menu (UL) of the LI containing the span clicked.

By default, the child UL is hidden via CSS.. but when expand is clicked, I'd like to show it.

For example, see my code below...

```
<li id="menu-item-15031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-page-parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-15031"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/">Automotive Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-15039" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-15039"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/window-tinting/">Window Tinting</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-15033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-484 current_page_item menu-item-15033"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/car-window-tinting/">Car Window Tinting</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-15040" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15040"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/computer-cut-film-system/">Computer Cut Window Tint System</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-15041" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15041"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/solar-window-tint/">Solar Window Tint</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-15042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15042"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/custom-tint-designs/">Custom Tint Designs</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-15043" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15043"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/removing-window-tint/">Removing Window Tint</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-15044" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15044"><a href="http://www.tintworld.com/automotive-services/window-tint-regulations/">Window Tint Regulations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<span class="arrow"></span>
</li>
```

I know the jQuery is super easy but honestly I'm exhausted and can't wrap my mind around it right now.

Please help me. :)

Comment: "honestly I'm exhausted and can't wrap my mind around it right now" => get some rest and come back to it tomorrow if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of these. Please rest ur tired mind :)

```
$(".arrow").click( function () {
 $(this).closest("li").find("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Or

```
 $(".arrow").click( function () {
 $(this).prev("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Or

```
 $(".arrow").click( function () {
 $(this).siblings("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Comment: Because `.sub-menu` is more than one in children of `li`, I think that it must be select with direct child selector `>`.

Comment: `span.arrow` has got to stop, no offense. Why would you over-qualify your selectors like this? `$('.arrow')` would have been just as effective and probably more performant. And it wouldn't rely on HTML.

Comment: @ZenMaster  Sorry. I'll change it. Im a micro optimizing freak. I tend to think that there are multiple elements with `class=arrow` so i tend to put the element name with it to simplify the search for the JS engine

Comment: The "search" is done **right-to-left**. Adding `span` can only degrade the performance. And if you have multiple HTML elements with the same class that shouldn't perform the same function - you should distinguish them by something else than their element type.

Comment: Thank you @ZenMaster. I just changed it. :)

I think I've been misdirected by reading an article long time back. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this.

Comment: @NOX wont `find` take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$("span").click(function(thisElement)
{
  $("#menu-item-15031 > ul").css("display","block");
});
```

You can use this also:

```
$(".arrow").click( function () {
  $(this).closest("li").find("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: `:O` REALLY this is a solution?